# Nutrition Planning Help for Lean Muscle and Strength

Tags: muscle, strength, nutrition, nutrition-information, meal-plan

Right now my main goal is total body transformation. I am on a caloric deficit and getting stronger each week and have lost about 10 lbs of fat so far from 170 to 160. My target weight goal is 150. Eventually I’m going to need to change my strategy for continuing to build strength and muscle. What next should I be focussing on?

My goal is to be as strong as possible at a certain weight (for now let’s just say that’s 150) with a low body fat percentage.

Currently my plan includes… 1,920 calories each day, 168 grams of carbs, 168 grams of protein, and 64 grams of fat.

Thanks for your input and help.

Comment: How tall are you? What's your workout regimen like? I see your meal plan takes into account the macronutrients, but what about the micronutrients? Are you getting all your vitamins and minerals? Are you supplementing them? If you add some info on this, it should be easier to provide an answer.

Comment: I train in powerlifting using the conjugate method 4 times a week and planning on adding a cardio day soon to help with gpp. I eat vegetables everyday but I'm not currently tracking micronutrients in the same way. I supplement with creatine, glutamine, protein, alpha lipoic acid, trans reservital, calogen, and zma

Comment: I'm 5 feet and 6 inches

Answer (score 1):

At first calculate your Basal metabolic rate. For your height and weight it will be ~1600 cal/day, I don't know your age. Then add how many calories you burn doing basic activities. There are many ways to do this. For example multiply BMR with

- 1.2 points for a person who does little to no exercise
- 1.37 points for a slightly active person who does light exercise 1–3 days a week
- 1.55 points for a moderately active person who performs moderate exercise 3–5 days a week
- 1.725 points for a very active person who exercises hard 6–7 days a week
- 1.9 points for an extra active person who either has a physically demanding job or has a particularly challenging exercise routine

If you want build muscle and strength in long term, you should have your calorie intake greater than number you calculated. But only about 100 - 300 if you don't want to gain fat. Maintain the same ratio of macronutrients. Every day eat vegetable and fruit and have **variet** diet. Eat a lot of Omega-3 fatty acids, for example from fish or suplement it. In the winter suplement vitamin D3. Instead of fast sugars eat complex carbohydrates. Eat most proteins from animal sources. Most of proteins eat near exercise. Hope it helps :)