# Workouts with 80 lbs. Kettlebell and Two 40 lbs. Dumbbells to build Muscle

Tags: workout-routines, dumbbells, kettlebell

Background on me: I'm 19 and I've been lifting for about 1.5 years now but more consistently for the past month and have been doing on-off for the past couple months since August, and as my university has kicked everyone off campus, now I’m back home with less distraction and focused on myself more. Since I started lifting, Went from weighing 210 at 5’11 with a ton of body fat and couldn’t do a push up to 170 and doing that and much more. I would say my current body fat is around 15-17%. All of my lifting was from CrossFit.

**My goal during this quarantine is to build muscle and lose body fat percentage** but all I have is an **80 lbs. Kettlebell** (I can do 25 straight KB swings in the first go and 6 straight KB cleans per arm in the first go) and **two 10lbs. dumbells and two 40 lbs. dumbbell** (I can do 6 reps of 50 lbs. both dumbbells standing military press). What are workouts I can employ to accomplish my goal?

**EDIT:** I have the following question, for me to achieve my aforementioned goals, what should my nutrition look like? Should I be in a caloric deficit or surplus? I'm basically sitting at a laptop all day and then I work out for about an hour in the evening (trying to do mornings now too), and I am working out 5-6 days a week.

Comment: American swings or russian swings on the kettlebell swings? I ask because you referenced crossfit.

Comment: Oh I meant 25 Russian Swings, but I can do 20 American KB swings straight on the first go @getbackintofitness

Comment: I'd break up the swings into sets of 10 every minute on the minute then if you can make it 5 minutes (or 10 minutes. ) yes, you'll be standing around a bit,  but you'll end up getting in a lot more reps with max power this way.  There's another protocol you can do involving swings & push ups. Set a timer 30 sec,, 30 sec, 30 sec, 1 minute 30 sec. You'd do 5 swings when the timer goes off (20 swings total), then do it over with pushups. 60 swings, 60 pushups total - 18 minutes. Modify accordingly to how you feel

Comment: @Parzivalz13 Maybe post your edit as an Answer, so that people can understand it better (and upvote it!)

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Thank you for the comment, I just made it an answer, check it out, and let me know what you think!

Comment: @Parzivalz13 Solid! Thanks for sharing so much detail, I think it could help other folks who read this.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann No problem! Do you happen to know the answer to my question in my Edit remark?

Comment: @Parzivalz13 To me, "lose weight while building muscle" screams `eat less but with a higher proportion of protein`. The classic trick from boxers and wrestlers cutting weight (both short and long term) is to leave out the potatoes from their usual steak+potato+salad meals. I also reduce dairy and eliminate calorific liquids (milk, juice, and of course soda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally as an update to my question: I am now doing Monday - Push, Tuesday - CrossFit workout geared towards Leg exercises, Wednesday - Pull, Thursday - CrossFit workout geared towards Push exercises, Friday - Leg, Saturday - CrossFit workout geared towards Pull exercises.

With the equipment I have (I also have two 10 lbs. dumbbells), here is what my workouts look like, and I am still in the process of getting a bench for the pullovers and some other exercises such as a flat bench DB press with added time under tension because 40 lbs. is too light.

Push -
1. 3x8-10 DB standing overhead press.
2. 3x8-10 DB floor presses
3. 3x6-8 DB pullovers but emphasize and use the chest more/do as many elevated complete pushups as possible/the jumping pushups/plyo pushups.
4. 8x15-20 KB both arms bicep curls/4x3-6 DB both arms bicep curls.
5. 8x15-20 side lateral arm raises with something ~10 lbs.
6. 3x8-12 DB Arnold Presses
7. Farmer’s carry with KB, the other arm has 40 lb. dumbbell 50 steps each arm/if you can’t do this do more pushups as in high rep normal proper pushups.

Pull -
1. 3x8-12 bent over DB rows both arms at same time.
2. 3x6-8 DB pullovers but with back and lats/3x10 KB one arm swings each arm.
3. 8x15-20 KB both arms bicep curls/4x3-6 DB both arms bicep curls.
4. 6-8x12-15 both arms DB shrugs
5. 3x5-10 standing upright DB rows both arms
6. 6-8x6-8 KB rack pulls.
7. 3x8-12 DB renegade rows.
8. 3x8-15 DB standing hammer curls.

Leg -
1. 3x8-10 DB Bulgarian Split squats each leg
2. 3x15-20 KB goblet squats
3. 3x20 DB deadlifts
4. 3x20 walking lunges each leg.
5. 3x15-20 DB calf raises.
6. 20 45 Lb. Russian Plate twists (R/L = 1), bicycles until tired

Answer (score 2):

Chest:

- push ups - a lot of variants
- butterflies with dumbbells lying on the ground
- pullover with dumbbell (need some bench or chair)
- and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byxD_y2e_L8

Back:

- one arm dumbbell rows
- pullover
- sumo deadlifts with kettlebell
- lying back extension
- shoulders shrugs dumbbells

Shoulders:

- overhead press
- front raise
- bent-over dumbbell lateral raise
- lateral raise

Triceps

- tricep kickbacks
- diamond push ups
- one arm over head extensions
- bench dip - you can use chair
- French press

Legs

- squats
- squats
- squats
- lunges
- calf raise
- Romanian deadlifts

Then

- bicep curl
- variants of sit-ups
- plank
- some crossfit exercises with dumbbells

**Always make sure of good technique!** Really sure.

If you want to lose fat focus on healthy and variet diet and read this: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/41792/33015

Comment: Romanian deadlifts with what? A lot of these exercises as well require an insane amount of strength and muscle which I do not have yet to do with 40 lbs. dumbbells such as the one arm overhead extensions. If you want, you can read my question background to gain context on how much strength I may possibly have.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Start with exercices you can do. You will become stronger over time and can do more exercises. Romanian deadlift with dumbbells, if you aren't so strong, do sumo deadlifts and you will become stronger. You can buy some expander for exercises like lateral raise, it is cheap and effective.

Comment: The RDLs should work great with the KB.